# Python: find differences in two dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have the following problem: given two dicts with article-IDs as keys and title+author as values. I'd like to compare the two dicts using the article-IDs: If the the article IDs have different titles/authors, I'd like to create a mapping, consisting of a string which first outputs the old article ID and title and author AND the new ID with the corresponding title and author.

Example:

```
old = {u'2014_en_1': u'Letter A\tauthor A\n', u'2014_en_2': u'Explanation\tauthor B\n', u'2014_en_3': u'Conclusion\tauthor C\n'}
new = {u'2014_en_1': u'Welcome\tauthor XY\n', u'2014_en_2': u'Letter A\tauthor A\n', u'2014_en_3': u'Conclusion\tauthor C\n', u'2014_en_4': u'Explanation\tauthor B\n',}

for k, v in old.iteritems():
    if old[k] != new[k]:
        print k + "\t" + old[k] + # HOW can I find the corresponding article in new?
```

So, the desired output should be:

```
[]    []    2014_en_1    Welcome\tauthor XY
2014_en_1    Letter A\tauthor A    2014_en_2    Letter A\tauthor A
2014_en_2    Explanation\tauthor B    2014_en_4    Explanation\tauthor B
2014_en_3    Conclusion\tauthor C    2014_en_3    Conclusion\tauthor C
```

How can I do this? It's tricky because it's possible that the new dict could have new articles (or vice versa) :/
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you reverse your `old` mapping so that values (title, authors) become keys instead.

Then you can just iterate over `new` and try to match the IDs:

```
old_reverse = {v: k for k, v in old.items()}
for k, v in new.iteritems():
    try:
        old_k = old_reverse[v]
        print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (old_k, repr(v), k, repr(v),)
    except KeyError:
        print "[]\t[]\t%s\t%s" % (k, repr(v),)
```

Note that I've used `repr` to make the output a little more readable. Instead, you may want to apply some string manipulation of your own to get the desired output format.

Dictionaries are unsorted collections in Python. If you want to have them sorted, you can use an extra step by storing the output in a list of tuples and then print it sorted:

```
# Flip the dict
old_reverse = {v: k for k, v in old.items()}

# Map new VS old
data = []
for k, v in new.iteritems():
    try:
        old_k = old_reverse[v]
        data.append((old_k, v, k, v,))
    except KeyError:
        data.append((None, None, k, v,))

# Print them sorted
for old_k, old_v, k, v in sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[0]):
    print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (
        old_k if old_k is not None else "[]",
        repr(old_v) if old_k is not None else "[]",
        k, 
        repr(v),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proposition! :) This is exactly what I wanted to do! And...wow, in only 7 lines! :O
What I wanted to ask: is it possible to get the output kind of sorted, maybe s.t. first the new articles with no correspondence in the old dict are printed, and after art_1 from the old dict which belongs to article X in the new dict?

Comment: @MarkF6: It's possible, but it involves an extra step where you store the data in a list and print them sorted. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get all keys   
keys = set(old.keys()).union(set(new.keys()))

# Reverse the new dict
new_reverse =  {v:k for k,v in new.items()}

# Loop keys and output
for k in keys:
    if k in old:
        if old[k] != new[k]:
            v = old[k]
            k_in_new = new_reverse[v]
            v_in_new = new[k_in_new]
        else:
            k_in_new = k
            v_in_new = v

        print '%s %s %s %s' % (k, old[k], k_in_new, v_in_new)
    else:
        print '[] [] %s %s' % (k, new[k])
```